# How to use ajax PHP search?

Tags: php, ajax, search, full-text-search

I'm having a search box that it will show all available data in the drop down menu, I'm gonna change it to something like google search, I mean if we type a word, based on that it will show data on the drop down menu. 
here is my code:

```
                        <?php foreach($hotelslocationsList as $locations): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $locations->id;?>"><?php echo $locations->name;?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

How can I change it like that?
I highly appreciate your help 
Thanks

Comment: Use https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ . The one word that describe what are you searching for is 'typeahead'.